# Multiple Regex Validation against a value

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to validate a text box input with below requirement

1. Text must be integer
2. Value of text must be between a predefined Max Value and predefined Min Value

** I don't want to use RangeAttribute.I want to use regular expression which I want to store in database and will get applicable when View will get rendered.

How we can do this in c# using multiple regex?

Comment: Are you using ViewModels or is this a ASP.NET Webpage project? You can do this in different ways but we need more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you want to restrict it in HTML, so you are sure the value you will receive is already a number you can do it [like this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_number.asp):

```
 Quantity (between 1 and 5): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

**IF** this is an MVC project, you should restrict this in your ViewModel by setting your property to be an Integer (int), use annotations to enforce things like

`[Required]`
or
`[Range(10, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]`

**Depending on what your project is built in (Webpages or MVC) this can be done differently.**